# Process cannot access the file as it is used by another process

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, filesize

I am trying to create windows batch script to check the size of file after it is downloaded but it fails with this message.
The Process cannot access the file as it is used by another process
2048 was unexpected at this time.
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
@echo off
d:\wget.exe ... 
Rem this wget process downloads tst_file.xml

set file="tst_file.xml"
set maxbytesize=2048

for /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (echo file is less than 2KB)
```

Comment: have you tried using `start /wait wget.exe ...` to ensure the process is complete?

Comment: If I remove the `wget` command from your code, everything else works properly. For this reason, I believe the issue is with the `wget` command itself, and I suspect that you have `tst_file.xml` open somewhere.

Comment: Downloading files from an untrusted source (like the Internet) is surely going to trigger anti-malware software for a quick scan. You can temporarily disable your anti-malware suite to verify this.

Comment: i tried with start /wait , but still same error

Comment: It is trusted source

Comment: Is the source trusted by you or by your anti-malware services?

Comment: We are already using this external service to download files from the trusted source.....just that we need to get the file size of the downloaded file and we are stuck with the error

Answer (score 0):

Consider this alteration.

```
@echo off
d:\wget.exe ... 
Rem this wget process downloads tst_file.xml

set "file=tst_file.xml"
set maxbytesize=2048

if not exist "%file%" (
    @echo '%file%' does not exist.
    goto :SKIP_CHECK
)

for /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (echo file is less than 2KB)

:SKIP_CHECK
```

### Notes

- If the file doesn't exist, the FOR loop will not be able to get the file size, and the LSS comparison will blow up with no operand to compare.

  - If you had quoted each of the vars (e.g. `if "%size%" LSS "%maxbytesize%" ...`), it wouldn't have blown up. However, it would have performed a lexical comparison, which when compared to anything would evaluate to true.
- In batch, if you use double quotes around *only* the value in a `SET` command, the quotes *will be included in the value*. Even though it looks unorthodox, put quotes around the whole `<variable>=<value>` expression.
- If you skip tokenization and get the entire line (i.e. `tokens=*`), you'll be able to handle files with spaces in the name.